# How to keep text label in view when swiping to reveal edit actions in tableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, autolayout, uilabel

What I want is to **keep the text label in view** while the cell is sliding out. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

*What I've got:*

[image: My cell with text label slid out of view]

**Desired:**

[image: Desired]

Comment: You can temporary store the text in your viewController at the swipe moment, then retrieve it when your swipe is finish. And you can add some code to show us how you do

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion (haven't tried this myself):

If you are using auto-layout, add constraint to align the label and the cell view (not the content view) on leading.
If you are not using auto-layout, subclass the cell view and adjust frame of the label on layoutSubviews.